# I cut the colour coding off new light fixture -- how can I find which wires are hot and neutral?

Tags: electrical

I've shortened a new light fixture, by cutting the cable, when I should've just rolled it up into the cap. Now I don't know which wire is which, they're all a clear colour. Original ends had black on one wire. Don't know what to do, help, all 3 wires are silver....

[image]

Comment: Include some pictures of the wires, fixture and instructions.

Comment: You should always be able to edit your own posts (without waiting for review). But that requires that "you" are "You" and not "you, under a different account" https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Welcome to DIY StackExchange. Please tell if you have a multimeter? If not that would be a much longer story.

Answer (score 10):

I’m going to answer assuming that the lamp takes a standard “Edison” screw-in bulb and you have a multimeter with a continuity test mode. Also, the wire colors listed assume you are in North America.

Hold one probe to the contact at the bottom of the socket and find the wire that has continuity. That is your hot (black).

Hold one probe to the screw threads inside the socket. The wire that has continuity is your neutral (white).

The last wire should be ground. You can confirm by testing continuity to the outer shell of the docket of any metal part of the fixture frame.

Comment: What does the picture show that you took before modifying it?

Answer (score 3):

Normally there is a small physical difference in the insulation on the wires - one side will be smooth, the other will have ridges or lines. Can't see that level of detail in your picture, but if you closely examine the cut off end you may find that difference, and that will indicate which side is hot.

Comment: doesn't really matter which side is hot, the most important is to wire the ground correctly (if there's a ground on a light fixture, there must be some kind of good reason)

Comment: @njzk2 -- getting the hot lead correct is important, too; if it's wrong there's a shock hazard when you unscrew the bulb, because the screw part of the bulb is hot.

Comment: turn of the power in the fixture before unscrewing anything, please. You don't _know_ that this wire is done how you think it is. (And you can't really have any idea at all if going via an outlet)